# Twitter error 34: "Sorry, that page does not exist" on: twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/flecpoint.json?count=25

Tags: php, json, twitter

A while back, I created a simple Twitter status message reader in PHP. It uses the twitter json feed located on `https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/flecpoint.json?count=25`. It reads the timeline, caches it and later checks again if there are new statuses. Nothing fancy.

Everything worked fine, until a few weeks back, where I suddenly experienced the `"Sorry, that page does not exist" (code 34)` error.

From that point on, sometimes we got the error, and sometimes everything worked fine. (I disabled cache to be sure the API was actually working)
In the beginning I thought it would be an error on Twitter's side, but the problem keeps appearing every so often.

I am 100% sure nothing has changed in my code. I have been googling this but haven't found anything useful to me yet.

For completeness' sake, here is my code with which I read the json file;

```
$apiUrl = 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/' . $user . '.json?count=25';
$curl   = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

// send request
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

**Does anyone have experience with this error?**

Comment: Tried contacting Twitter about this? might be a doc change or something.

Comment: I've had bad experience with getting replies from Twitter. So I have not tried it for this problem. Might be a good idea to give it another shot, yes.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/151611/maurice) your account? If yes then you can merge it. Have a look at [this question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/187824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the API that you are using was "unofficial" and unsupported. It's not even the version 1 API.

[Version 1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) API:

> http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=_mauris

[Version 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) requires OAuth authentication.

Reminder: Read the Docs (:

Comment: Oh, nice find! As far as reading docs go; I'll spare you the details, but I've spent many hours going through them at the time of writing this script. Did not find anything useful for what I wanted and finally decided to go with this url which I've found by googling.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for looking this up and helping me out. I consider you a twitter docs wizard now ;-)

Comment: I see. I'm really glad it helped (: